# Antd Select Component mode multiple, checkbox styling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, antd

Using **antd** NPM package, select component, in multiple mode, by default checkbox shows up at right. I want to align it to left and style it like tick mark in the box followed by a label. Also, need search box separately please refer screenshot added. I wanted to know it is even possible? I don't want to use any other package.

[image]

Searched a lot but unable to get any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I need to create a similar component.. Can you share the approach you used?

Comment: Hey @devb, Are you using ANTD? I settled for existing UI of ANTD. But if you are using ANTD, you need to customize a lot. You may use custom dropdown to add search input before menu, https://ant.design/components/select/#components-select-demo-custom-dropdown-menu and then in options add checkbox component. But it will be lots of coding. First decide whether it worth it and then go for it.

Comment: thanks for the response...I've customised it , will try to frame an answer for anyone else looking for it...

Comment: @devb you got any breakthrough in above

Answer (score 7):

It is possible, but it breaks the [Design System](https://ant.design/docs/spec/introduce) of `antd`.

You already have a [`Select`](https://ant.design/components/select/) component which implements **checking**, **drop-down** and **searching**:

[image]

In your case, you need to implement and test it by yourself with the composition of `antd` components:

- `Input.Search`
- `Checkbox`
- `Dropdown`
- `Menu`

Minimal example:

```
const menu = (
  <Menu>
    <Menu.Item>
      <Checkbox>User1</Checkbox>
    </Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>
      <Checkbox>User2</Checkbox>
    </Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
);
export default function App() {
  return (
    <FlexBox>
      <Dropdown.Button overlay={menu}>Dropdown</Dropdown.Button>
    </FlexBox>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Q-57805672-CustomDropdown]

Answer (score 1):

Yes I agree with @lamhungypl, that you can use isSelected property.
Select component has menuItemSelectedIcon property.

```
    menuItemSelectedIcon={({ isSelected }) => (
      <span>
        {isSelected ? 'yes': 'no'}
      </span>
    )}

    <Select
     menuItemSelectedIcon={({ isSelected }) => (
      <span>
        {isSelected ? 'yes': 'no'}
      </span>
     )}
    >
     ...
    </Select>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xbtv2.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Antd Select is built on top of [rc-select](https://github.com/react-component/select) [[1](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/select/index.tsx#L128)], so you can find ideas in their repo, note that some props are omitted by Antd, recheck the type definition.

Custom icon with `isSelected` prop will help you

[image]