# Adding checkboxes in antD select

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to add checkboxes to the options in select antD (with select all feature). Just wrapping the options is not helping because the checks are not binding with the options.

```
    import React from "react";
import { Select, Radio ,Checkbox} from 'antd';
const { Option } = Select;

const children = [];
for (let i = 10; i < 36; i++) {
  children.push(<Option key={i.toString(36) + i}><Checkbox>{i.toString(36) + i}</Checkbox></Option>);
}

function handleChange(value) {
  console.log(`Selected: ${value}`);
}



export const Test = () => {
  const [size, setSize] = React.useState('default');

  const handleSizeChange = e => {
    setSize(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <>
    
    <Select
        mode="tags"
        size={size}
        placeholder="Please select"
        defaultValue={['a10', 'c12']}
        onChange={handleChange}
        style={{ width: '100%' }}
      >
        {children}
      </Select>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57805672/antd-select-component-mode-multiple-checkbox-styling

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Antd Select Component mode multiple, checkbox styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57805672/antd-select-component-mode-multiple-checkbox-styling)