# how to implement the React ANTD debounce with multi-select checkbox and retain the selected values

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro, debouncing

so my requirement is to have a multi-select checkbox debouncing using React ANTD.
something similar as below.
on search
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ss55.png)

once selected the dropdown should also retain the values as below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMD51.png)

Tried code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-crt2qv?file=demo.js

Comment: this is not a question, this is a whole task to be done, please search for other demonstrations, implement some code yourself first, then if you get stuck, ask your question here.

Comment: Hey @AgilAtakishiyev I have added the sample code which I am trying out, basically I am able to capture the values but on select, the checkbox is not working and in the place of placeholder I wanted to show the count instead of selected values.

Comment: there is a similar question and suitable answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57805672/antd-select-component-mode-multiple-checkbox-styling

Comment: @Pavan Did you menage to do that? I have same issue. All I was able to find was searching input debounce. No checbox